# .sh Help Please. Trying to convert this to .bat

Tags: bash, batch

I have a .batch file with switches and parameters how would i run that in a bash file?

Any help would be appreciated

```
@echo off
title runserver
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe" -Xmx815m -cp bin;lib/*; com.rs.Launcher true true false
pause
```

How could u get a bash file to run the same way as the batch file?

Comment: Batch files came after (bash) shell scripts so there can be similarities, but there's no easy automatic translation. The post from djeikyb below looks like a reasonable alternative.

Comment: Yes the code posted by djeikyb does work, the only problem now is that it wont stay open...